# Mysql below v8.0 assigning row_number (partition by) with @num

Tags: mysql, partition, row-number

My MySQL version is below v8.0 and I would like to assign row_number() over (partition by AAB) with the table below. I tried the following codes and it did not work.How can I get it work?

```
select 
@part:=AAB as AAB,
AAG,AAD,
@num:=if(@part=AAB,@num:=@num+1,1) as rank
from IMPO_MEMB_AAAE a, (select @part:=null,@num:=0) b
order by AAB,AAG;
```

[image: Table to rank]

Comment: 1) `@part` must be re-assigned after `@num` calculation (now you compare `AAB` with current, assigned in previous line, value in a variable, not with stored for previous row), swap them in `SELECT` clause; 2) `null` is wrong initial value, use `0` (or `-1`) instead; 3) you'll get row number, not rank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem highlights the issue with using variables for this form of computation. Your issue is that you are evaluating `@num` later in the `SELECT` list than you evaluate `@part` and as it happens `@part` gets assigned its new value *before* `@num` is computed, meaning that `@part=AAB` is always true. You can work around this by placing `@num` before `@part` in the `SELECT` list, but as they say in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html):

> The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined. For example, there is no guarantee that SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1 evaluates @a first and then performs the assignment.

As it happens it generally does seem to work that way so until you upgrade you can probably use this query:

```
select 
@num:=if(@part=AAB,@num:=@num+1,1) as rank,
@part:=AAB as AAB,
AAG,AAD
from IMPO_MEMB_AAAE a, (select @part:=null,@num:=0) b
order by AAB,AAG;
```

Output:

```
rank    AAB         AAG                     AAD
1       10000751    2020-01-02 16:06:00     41
1       10033980    2020-01-02 22:55:00     40
1       10041030    2020-01-02 22:50:00     41
2       10041030    2020-01-02 23:53:00     40
3       10041030    2020-01-02 23:53:00     40
4       10041030    2020-01-02 23:53:00     40
1       10049083    2020-01-02 12:58:00     41
2       10049083    2020-01-02 12:58:00     40
3       10049083    2020-01-02 12:58:00     40
4       10049083    2020-01-02 12:58:00     41
5       10049083    2020-01-02 12:58:00     40
6       10049083    2020-01-02 12:58:00     40
1       10061286    2020-01-02 05:44:00     41
1       10081536    2020-01-02 12:11:00     41
1       10092699    2020-01-02 19:12:00     41
1       10116976    2020-01-02 22:03:00     41
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c0d06f8e66d5f5030b300e0bdda69d2f)